# CSS - make background image a link

Tags: html, css

I have placed a background image inside a div but would like it to be an active link to another page, and also maybe light up when hovered over. Here is the HTML & the CSS, any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks...

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 img1"><a href="football.html">Football</a></div>



  .img1 {
    background-image: url(https://....);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
```

EDIT: full code;

```css
  .img1 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472108482137-8df36ccf0d7b?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

.img2 {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/05/28/16/37/sport-788105_960_720.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: xx-large;

   }

.img3 {
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528543606781-2f6e6857f318?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80);
    background-size: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: xx-large;


}
```

```html
<!--   Containers center and horizontally pad your content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- create row inside container / row is wrapper for column-->
    <div class="row">

        <!-- now create 3 columns with small breakpoint -->
           <div class="col-sm-4 brdcol img1"> <a href="watersports.html">Water Sports</a></div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 brdcol img2"><a href="football.html">Football</a></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 brdcol img3"><a href="">Hiking</a></div>
        <!-- columns centred in page with parent container -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to go to football.html wherever the user clicks on the image, or do you want them to go to football.html if they click on the word Football and to a different place if they click elsewhere on the image? (also, should img2 be img1?)

Comment: if they click anywhere inside the column, on the word football or anywhere on the background image. I don't want the dimensions of the background image to change at all, just want it to be clickable.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or...? Perhaps you could put up working code in a snippet.

Comment: yes using bootstrap. I will edit the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to have a clickable image - is to wrap your div element(the one with background image) with anchor tag, like this:

```
<a href="football.html"><div class="col-sm-4 img1">Football</div></a>
```

Comment: thanks, but this then pushes the other columns on the page below, so the top row only has one column now.

Comment: try to add this class "col-sm-4" to your anchor element as it is now becomes the parent element. It should keep your styles and layout looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need a single `anchor` tag with some CSS.

```
<a class="photo" href="website.net/link"></a>
```

CSS

```
.photo {
    background-image: url('http://www.thinksnaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/images-background.jpg');
    background-size: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-clip: border-box;
    transition: background-size 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.07,1.41,.82,1.41);

    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.photo:hover {
    background-size: 500px;
}
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want the dimensions of the image to change, just want to make it a clickable link